# Duplicate Entry When Update

Tags: mysql

I want to remove space characters at the end of my data. So I update it with below query

```
UPDATE dwhdb.DimProductConsolidate 
SET LoyaltyVariantArticleCode = REPLACE(LoyaltyVariantArticleCode, ' ', '')
WHERE LoyaltyVariantArticleCode LIKE '% '
```

It runs for a while, then this error message popping up.

[image]

It should be impossible for a duplicate value in this table because I already set a unique key with a combination of CompanyReference and LoyaltyVariantArticleCode. I check it and there was no duplicate value with CompanyReference `9914` and LoyaltyVariantArticleCode `PGL/P13471` and it didn't even have a space at the end of the characters.

My question is, why this article code get inside my query when I already using where `'% '` ? And is there a way for me to update the data?

Edit: Below is my CREATE code

```
CREATE TABLE `DimProductConsolidate` (
    `ID` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `GenericArticleCode` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `CompanyReference` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `EcomVariantArticleCode` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `LoyaltyVariantArticleCode` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `VariantArticleName` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `BarcodeEAN` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `MerchandisingCode` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `BrandName` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `GroupName` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CategoryName` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `EcomCategoryLvl1` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `EcomCategoryLvl2` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `EcomCategoryLvl3` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `EcomCategoryLvl4` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `DivisionName` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ColourInternal` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SizeInternal` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ColourExternal` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `SizeExternal` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ProductGender` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CompanyName` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ProductImageURL` VARCHAR(512) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ProductType` VARCHAR(200) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ListPrice` DECIMAL(10,0) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `Quantity` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `ListedTime` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `CreatedDate` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `CompanyReference` (`CompanyReference`, `LoyaltyVariantArticleCode`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `GenericArticleCode` (`GenericArticleCode`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `EcomVariantArticleCode` (`EcomVariantArticleCode`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `BarcodeEAN` (`BarcodeEAN`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `MerchandisingCode` (`MerchandisingCode`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `BrandName` (`BrandName`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `GroupName` (`GroupName`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `CategoryName` (`CategoryName`),
    INDEX `EcomCategoryLvl1` (`EcomCategoryLvl1`),
    INDEX `EcomCategoryLvl2` (`EcomCategoryLvl2`),
    INDEX `EcomCategoryLvl3` (`EcomCategoryLvl3`),
    INDEX `EcomCategoryLvl4` (`EcomCategoryLvl4`),
    INDEX `DivisionName` (`DivisionName`),
    INDEX `LoyaltyVariantArticleCode` (`LoyaltyVariantArticleCode`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=22497389
;
```

Comment: Can you please share with us the `CREATE` statement of your table?

Comment: TRIM is the standard function for this

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos I already edit and put it on the question, please take a look

Comment: @Strawberry omg, it works when I use TRIM, thanks a lot

Comment: The error message tells that you have 2 separate values which differs with trailing spaces only. For example, `'ABC'` and `'ABC '`. After trailing space(s) remove the values become identical which causes duplicate violation.

Comment: See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e1903d527b58be7d41815e77ae53828e